# Online FIFA tournaments

Tags: fifa-18, fifa-world, fifa-online-3

I've always played FIFA with my friends in gaming cafes/on laptop and have never played it online. I was thinking about starting to play it online but I lack info about it.

Since my laptop has become really old I was confused whether I should buy a new gaming laptop or should I buy a gaming console. I don't know if a laptop gamer can play in the online competitions. If there's no such restriction then I'll be buying a gaming laptop, otherwise, I'll have to buy a console.
It would be great to know if a laptop gamer can participate along with console gamers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing FIFA cross-platform is not possible, but any platform has their own online mode.

You can play on PC/Laptop and will be playing with other PC users or you can play on PS4 and play with other PS4 users or Xbox with Xbox or... you get the idea.

You can *not* play on PC with other players that are on a PS4, Xbox, etc. and vice versa.

So you'll want to check where your friends play their games in order to be able to join them. If they're all on PC you'll need a PC or Laptop version of FIFA as well in order to join them.

Comment: Are there regular online PC tournaments? Do you know about famous websites for PC gamers which organise such tournaments?

Comment: @VishalSharma Website recs are off-topic here, sorry. There are regular tournaments for any platform for FIFA 18 and there are even the already included FUT leagues.